# Get facebook friend Detail Using Id

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using facebook friend picker dialog and on the result, I am getting name and Profile Pic only.
How can I get all fields like Email, Bday, Phone no.. etc.

Comment: You can only get email and birthday from people that granted email and user_birthday permission to the app. And there is no way to get phone number

Comment: @WizKid Thank you for your reply, but I am not getting email and bday also. Already have set extra for permission in Friend picker dialog.

Could you please guide me how to get or if any link is there.

Comment: Did the friends grant email and user_birthday permission to your app? You can only get it from people that granted the permissions to you

Comment: @WizKid when user login I am getting everything. In my app, I am using friend picker dialog. So can't ask friends for these permissions. So can I get the detail of my friend or not.

Comment: I've answered that twice. You can only get email and birthday from people that granted email and user_birthday permission. So if your friends have not granted those permission you can not get it from them